# Could not find any way If a file transfer fails half way through using Putty PSFTP

Tags: putty, psftp

I know there is a command (reput) which we can use if a file transfer fails half way through. But how we can find out whether a file transfer fails half way through or not uisng psftp. Is there any command for this.

I am executing psftp.exe from a web application. This web application will pass a list of files to move to the server. And I can achieve this by using mput commands in the psftp. But ,During this file transfer , how can I find out which file transfer failed in half way through and accordingly i can make use of reput command to continue the file transfer from where it left off.

Comment: What web application? There's a native SFTP library for most languages. Use that, instead of running an external console application for the transfer.

Comment: From ColdFusion. But , I think that doesnt matter right?? , since my question is how we can find out whether a file transfer fails half way through or not uisng psftp/pscp

Comment: All that psftp/pscp tells you, is if a script went ok or not. You will never tell if it failed because a connection cannot be opened, source file does not exist, or is not readable, or target path does not exist, or is not writable, etc. Unless you try to parse the error message out of a log. While a library with a well defined API will tell you an exact reason.

Comment: Also, you keep asking questions (using multiple accounts), without responding to answers you are getting here.

Comment: thanks for your response. But , what you mean by "keep on asking questions"...Do you have any reference

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47263190/850848), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47262972/850848), [3](https://superuser.com/q/1268604/213663)

Comment: okay..I couldnt recollect every thing..completely messed up with something. Sorry... Answered the second one. but not able to mark as answer the first and second

Comment: Because you have posted 3 using a different account.

Comment: one last question . After that i will move this to chat. If there is no 100% in the pscp statistics then does it mean that file is not copied to remote server or copied to server but it is not fully transferred?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68812/discussion-between-user3742125-and-martin-prikryl).

Comment: Copied to server but it is not fully transferred.